# Basic Web Socket with ExpressJS and Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, node.js, sockets

I'm trying to build an ExpressJS websocket backend for a jQuery-based front end using HTML5 web sockets.

The ExpressJS backend code is literally copy-pasted from https://github.com/websockets/ws#expressjs-example

The javascript front end code is:

```
var socket = new WebSocket("ws://localhost:8080");

socket.onopen = function(){
    console.log( "OPENED : ", socket.readyState );
}

socket.onmessage = function(msg){
    console.log( msg );
}

socket.onclose = function(){
    console.log( "CLOSED : ", socket.readyState );
}

setTimeout(function(){
    socket.send('test');
}, 2000);
```

In Chrome, I'm receiving an error: "Connection closed before receiving a handshake response". I've looked online for a solution, but they are all socket.io based whereas I'm just using the NodeJS ws package.

Any tips would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: I have tried the code with a change in the backend code (removing the `app.use()` function and adding a handler for the home page where the frond end code is) and everything worked fine. Could you add more info about the error ? Is the front end hosted on the same server ?

Comment: @M.Sallam - Could you elaborate on what you did and post as an answer? The front end is hosted on the same server via express and serves the webpage. There's one port (3000) for regular express, and a second port (5000) for the web socket.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The back end code :

```
const express = require('express')
const http = require('http')
const WebSocket = require('ws')
var path = require('path')

const app = express()

app.get('/', (req, res) => {
  res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname + '/a.html'))
})

const server = http.createServer(app)
const wss = new WebSocket.Server({ server })

wss.on('connection', function connection (ws, req) {
  ws.on('message', function incoming (message) {
    console.log('received: %s', message)
  })

  ws.send('something')
})

server.listen(8080, function listening () {
  console.log('Listening on %d', server.address().port)
})
```

the only change is the `app.get` on line 8 instead of the `app.use` provided in the link you gave.

And the `a.html` file has only the front end script :

```html
<html>
  <head>

  </head>
  <body>
    <script>
      var socket = new WebSocket("ws://localhost:8080");

      socket.onopen = function () {
        console.log("OPENED : ", socket.readyState);
      }

      socket.onmessage = function (msg) {
        console.log(msg);
      }

      socket.onclose = function () {
        console.log("CLOSED : ", socket.readyState);
      }

      setTimeout(function () {
        socket.send('test');
      }, 2000);
    </script>
  </body>

</html>
```

And everything is working fine.

You said you are running the server on port 3000 and yet you are trying to connect to port 8080 in the front end code. Was that a mistake ?

Answer (score 0):

use [socket.io](https://socket.io/) the fasted and most reliable, it is far more easy to implement and configure.